# React props not auto-complete in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, components, react-props

[image]

I have a functional component like above (only js). After building the library and publishing, I import into my project but vscode doesn't suggest to me which props I need to use.

Below is my setting:

[image]

[image]

[image: vscode doesn't suggest me which props i need to use]

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check **[React TypeScript](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#typescript)**.

**React JavaScript** won't tell you any required props, and using TypeScript will help you achieve that.

#### Example:

```
type Data = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  address: string;
}

type Props = {
  sortable?: boolean;
  data: Data[];
  filters?: any;
}

function CommonTable(props: Props) {
  // code
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! but i don't want use React TypeScript

Comment: As far as I know, You need either TypeScript or Flow to achieve this behavior with VSCode. But do let me know if you found any other way. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). It works with JavaScript.

You'll need to install the `prop-types` package.

Example:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function Greeting({ otherPerson, you }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hi {otherPerson}!</h1>
      {you && <h1>I am {you}</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  otherPerson: PropTypes.string.required,
  you: PropTypes.string,
};

Greeting.defaultProps = {
  you: "ME",
};
```

Autocomplete should be working now.